# Lookup function within an email referencing two Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, lookup, dataextensions

I have subscribers going into one data extension giving a value for a column. 
For example: data extension name "Foodie" column name "FoodID" with a number in that field, i.e. 1234.

I have another data extension that will have the definition of that value, example: data extension name "FavoriteFoods" columns "FavoriteFood" and "FoodID" indicating i.e. 1234 equals Bananas

I am trying to return the lookup value  within an email but nothing is coming through here is my code:

`%%[
VAR @FF, @FoodID
SET @FoodID = [FoodID]
SET @FF = Lookup("FavoriteFoods", "FavoriteFood", "FoodID", @FoodID)
]%%`

and I use this:

`%%=v(@FF)=%%`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your lookup appears to be correct.  I'd utilize the `AttributeValue()` function and output `@FoodID`, just to make sure it has a value:

```
%%[
VAR @FF, @FoodID
SET @FoodID = AttributeValue("FoodID")
SET @FF = Lookup("FavoriteFoods", "FavoriteFood", "FoodID", @FoodID)
]%%
FoodID: %%=v(@FoodID)=%%
<br>Favorite food: %%=v(@FF)=%%
```

Perhaps you can provide a brief sample of the the `FavoriteFoods` data -- including the data types of each column?

Comment: FavoriteFoods has two columns:
FavoriteFood (text, it has a the word for the food, such as "Pizza")
FoodID (number, has the number id for that food, such as "1111",  also has the same FoodID value as in the "Foodie"DE.

Comment: Thanks @AdamSpriggs !
Still coming up blank.  Would the location of the Data extension be a factor?

Comment: So `@FoodID` has a value?  If the DE is in Shared Items, then you may need to include the `ent.` prefix on the DE name.

Comment: Yeah, FoodID has a value. All columns from both Data Extensions do. 
'm not sure if either DE is in Shared Items, I do know that they are not in the location, two different folders under "Data Extension"

When the subscribers enter the info, I get the number (1111) but the name for that only lives in the other DE and the email would state something like "Your favorite food is: BANANAS" (i'm sure you knew this, just revisiting for my own benefit.)

Comment: So does the `@FoodID` have a value _in your email_?  If you hardcode `set @FoodID = 1111` in your email does it work?

Comment: yep, hardcoded that to test and it shows.

Comment: There's your answer.  The data source you're using for send preview/test send doesn't have a FoodID value  -- or the value has trailing spaces or something.

Comment: thanks @AdamSpriggs ! Everything appeared to be fine in the both Date Extension so I ended up making a copy of the Foodies Data Extension for testing and it was displaying everything properly & I was receiving an odd error when trying to use it in a send preview. I had to call customer support. 
At least we know the code works! thanks again!